# Cannot import name 'PiCamera'

Tags: python, pi-3

I'm trying to use my PiCamera, and while doing that (writing some python code to use it), I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/picamera.py", line 1, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/picamera.py", line 1, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera
ImportError: cannot import name 'PiCamera'
```

The camera is working because I tested it in the command line: raspistill -o image.png

I am using Python 3.

Comment: try this import picamera pay attention to the capitalization

Comment: @SteveRobillard I did from picamera import PiCamera
Also I tried just to import picamera and then do:
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
But in both situations I receive the error from above.

Comment: try this pip3 install PiCamera then retry the import

Comment: @SteveRobillard : I've tried and what I get is: Requirement already satisfied

Comment: how did you fix the error ? I am having the same problem. If you could explain it would be nice of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I used python 3.4, and while compiling the code in terminal (python script.py) it was compiled in python 2.7.
I have both versions installed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html) docs:

> When trying out these scripts do not name your file `picamera.py`. Naming scripts after existing Python modules will cause errors when you try and import those modules (because Python checks the current directory before checking other paths).

You can't name your script `picamera.py`, otherwise, Python will think that's the module.

So you will have to rename your script to something else.

I like to call it `picam.py`